# PhpStorm remote debug with xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I want to debug with PHPstorm IDE and xdebug my site in the server. Locally works perfectly, but when i want configure to debug from the server i can't.

I installed xdebug in the server, with this configuration:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host=MY IP
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Then i setup in PHPSTORM in "Edit Configurations" a "PHP remote debug" and a "Server"

In the server i put:

```
Name: xxxx
Port: 80
Host: Url of my site
Debugger: Xdebug
I checked "Use Path Mapping" and in File/Directory i put my local    proyect path "/home/mysite"
In "Absolute path on the server" i put the path in the server where are the proyect: "/var/www/html/mysite"
```

In the "PHP remote debug" i put:

```
Name: xxxx
Servers: the server created previously
IDE key: PHPSTORM
```

With these settings did not work. I use Chrome with the extension Xdebug with Ide key PHPstorm enable.

What is lacking me to work?

Comment: Collect xdebug logs first and see 1) if it tries to connect to correct IP:port; 2) If it succeeds with connecting. If connection is failed -- possibly firewall somewhere between your server and your PC (could be anything: local firewall; router; server config that prevents outgoing connections on such port etc); 3) verify paths (remember: xdebug works with final/resolved paths only -- so double check for any symbolic links on remote etc)

Comment: In any case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm in case if you did not see it yet

Comment: Can you give me the output of Run -> Web Server Debug Validation tool please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem at work once when I freshly hatched. When XDebug is running on another server, the port of the XDebug engine is of course only open on the local system (the remote server).

The best way to get that port over to your development machine is to create a safe SSH tunnel between these two systems. On your local machine, in the ssh-config-file (often located under ~/.ssh/config), do the following:

```
Host example
    Hostname 192.168.2.1
    User johndoe
    LocalFoward 9200 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Now when -on console- you do

```
ssh example
```

it will connect to the remote system (192.168.2.1) with the username (login) johndoe and tunnel the port 9200 on the remote machine to the port 9000 on your local machine. Of course you can also use the same port for both.

I hope this helps. :)